# Can you use combinatorics to determine the average time needed for something?

Tags: combinatorics, time-series

So im building an graffitiprinter and I use a matrix so could it be possible if I know the time of one spray to calculate the avarege time to complete a picture. If I also knew the total amoents of spray I need in the picture?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit how it works? What is "one spray"? How does the matrix correspond to the result?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What I mean whit one spray is like when you spray a dot on the wall with a spraycan. The matrix is used to know how many dots that need to be sprayed

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but if you know how long it takes to paint one dot and you know how many dots you plan to paint overall, a simple multiplication of the two quantities will give you an estimate for the time to paint all the dots.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).